# getting error of "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code" while i try to display first name after successful login in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting error of "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code" while i try to display first name after successful login in ASP.NET MVC.

Model:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
 namespace club.Models
{
public class User
{
    int j;
  public string type1  { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember on this computer")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if user with given password exists in the database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_username">User name</param>
    /// <param name="_password">User password</param>
    /// <returns>True if user exist and password is correct</returns>
    /// 


    public bool IsValid(string _username, string _password)
    {
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\softwares\ASP.NET\club_hardik\club\App_Data\club.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
        {
            string _sql = @"SELECT [ContactNo],[type] FROM tblLogin " +
                   @"WHERE [ContactNo] = @u AND [Password] = @p";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(_sql, cn);
            Console.WriteLine(cmd);
            cmd.Parameters
                .Add(new SqlParameter("@u", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
                .Value = _username;
            cmd.Parameters
                .Add(new SqlParameter("@p", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
                .Value = Models.SHA1.Encode(_password);

            cn.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();
                type1 = reader.GetString(1);
                reader.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                reader.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using club.Models;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace club.Controllers
{
public class UserController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /User/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Member(User model)
    {

        var model1 = new M_Reg();
        using (var db = new clubDataContext())
        {
            var content = from p in db.M_Registarions
                          where p.M_ContactNo == model.UserName
                          select p;
            foreach (M_Registarion p in content)
            {
                model1.FName = p.M_Fname;

            }
        }
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult memberdisplay(User u)
    {

        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Models.User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (user.IsValid(user.UserName, user.Password))
            {

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, user.RememberMe);
                string a = (user.type1).ToString();
                string fixedStringOne = Regex.Replace(a, @"\s+", String.Empty);

                if (string.Equals(fixedStringOne, "member"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("member",user);
                }
                else if (fixedStringOne.Equals("admin"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Admin", "Admin");
                }
                else
                { }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!");
            }
        }
        return View(user);
    }
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

}
```

}
View:

```
@model club.Models.M_Reg
   @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Member";
    }
  <h2>Member</h2>
   @using (Html.BeginForm( ))
    {
     <div>
    <fieldset>

        <div class="editor-label">
           <span>welcome   @Model.FName </span>
```

> Here I am getting error of** Null Reference was unhandled by Usercode

```
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
```

}

When i debug line by line i get the 'firstname' from database but it does not display in View and getting error of "NullReference Exception". I don't know what is the meaning of this error. Help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Model` property in your view is `null`. You should pass the model you created in the `Member` action to the view:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Member(User model)
{
    var model1 = new M_Reg();
    // ...
    return View(model1);
}
```

Looking at your code, you have the same potential errors in your `memberdisplay` and `Login` actions.